# REGEX in Sublime How to select everything including line breaks up to an end point

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, sublimetext3

I have a client and we are moving their site from Squarespace to Wordpress. The export of posts from Squarespace produces tons of unnecessary code that I am trying to remove.

If I run this Regex in an online tester like regex101 it highlights exactly what I am looking for:

```
/\<hr \/><h3 style="white-space:pre-wrap;">YOU MAY ALSO LIKE:<\/h3>([\s\S]*?)<\/div>\]\]>/gms
```

UPDATE: here is how I use the expression in Sublime:

```
<hr \/><h3 style="white-space:pre-wrap;">YOU MAY ALSO LIKE:<\/h3>([\s\S]*?)<\/div>\]\]>
```

However, when I try to run this in Sublime it does not work.

Does anyone have any insight into what I need to do in order to get Sublime to work properly?

Here is the content for testing purposes: (if you paste this content into regex101.com and use the regex expression above it will highlight what I am trying to remove.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:excerpt="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/excerpt/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:wp="http://wordpress.org/export/1.2/">
  <channel>
    <title>CLIENT CLIENTLAST</title>
    <link>https://www.CLIENTDOMAIN.com</link>
    <pubDate>Tue, 05 Feb 2019 22:13:35 +0000</pubDate>
    <description />
    <language>en-US</language>
    <wp:wxr_version>1.2</wp:wxr_version>
    <wp:author>
      <wp:author_id>1055063081</wp:author_id>
      <wp:author_login>CLIENT</wp:author_login>
      <wp:author_email />
      <wp:author_display_name><![CDATA[CLIENT]]></wp:author_display_name>
      <wp:author_first_name><![CDATA[CLIENT]]></wp:author_first_name>
      <wp:author_last_name><![CDATA[CLIENTLAST]]></wp:author_last_name>
    </wp:author>
    <wp:category>
      <wp:cat_name><![CDATA[null - null]]></wp:cat_name>
      <wp:category_nicename>null-null</wp:category_nicename>
      <wp:category_parent />
    </wp:category>
    <item>
      <title>What if you looked at setbacks like this...</title>
      <link>/read/what-if-you-looked-at-setbacks-like-this</link>
      <content:encoded><![CDATA[
<p class="" style="white-space:pre-wrap;"><strong>P.S. </strong>To get where we’re headed… everyone’s got to come along. <a href="http://mail.CLIENTDOMAIN.com/public/webform/render_form/default/54059162ab2c79ad9748ecab5d91b62f/ftaf/j8q56xec9df941bkl0bkutruvho61/caywtervkjauiwcmovobcpcxwatgbdj?td=FkU7TlfUyInMpngpjQW4AgF0SHJPqflxpU8J2z0pRvVxtUn0xp-jMIiLxzCTMpnjAe3su9g3E9NLEnQnDBEgeuYhLAQAMvn8GQHtyNL1VcUn713nINRMyd1VD5Obt8qRKx2-YCrAlIRGO3RFH74C5eHlVwDjFWibgB55olOWUU835F6A9qSjewvA&amp;tid=2443574726270008515295681973702067450845120587963545907028920327188514310" target="_blank"><strong>Forward this</strong></a> to a friend who you know is up for a year of inclusive aspiration.<br><br><strong>Tweet it out: </strong><br><br><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=What%20if%20every%20obstacle%20in%20your%20path%20was%20a%20gift%20of%20Loving%20Kindness%20from%20your%20Higher%20Self?%20Suddenly%20setbacks%20become%20love%20notes%20inviting%20us%20into%20deeper%20exploration%20of%20our%20True%20Nature.%20Class%20w/%20%40CLIENTDOMAIN%20starts%204/1.%20Door%E2%80%99s%20open%3A%20CLIENTDOMAIN.com/heartcentered%20%23heartcentered" target="_blank"><strong>What if every obstacle in your path was a gift of Loving Kindness from your Higher Self? Suddenly setbacks become love notes, inviting us into deeper exploration of our True Nature.</strong></a><br><br><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Welcome%20and%20befriend%20it%20all.%20This%20is%20Loving%20Kindness%20training.%20This%20is%20how%20we%20create%20a%20New%20Earth.%20Class%20w/%20%40CLIENTDOMAIN%20starts%204/1.%20Door%E2%80%99s%20open%3A%20CLIENTDOMAIN.com/heartcentered%20%23heartcentered%20%23lovingkindness%20%23freewill" target="_blank"><strong>Welcome and befriend it all. This is Loving Kindness training. This is how we create a New Earth.</strong></a><br><br><strong>Click </strong><a href="https://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=https%3A//CLIENTDOMAIN.mykajabi.com/heart-centered-2021&amp;media=https%3A//mcusercontent.com/ed442308ef864ebe9e3b10cf4/images/590e1fc2-7457-4243-bcc3-0a853dfcb92b.png&amp;description=Welcome%20and%20befriend%20it%20all.%20This%20is%20Loving%20Kindness%20training.%20This%20is%20how%20we%20create%20a%20New%20Earth.%20Class%20w/%20%40CLIENTDOMAIN%20starts%204/1.%20Door%E2%80%99s%20open%3A%20CLIENTDOMAIN.com/heartcentered%20%23heartcentered%20%23lovingkindness%20%23freewill" target="_blank"><strong>here</strong></a><strong> to Pin or right click to download + share on Instagram.</strong></p><hr /><h3 style="white-space:pre-wrap;">YOU MAY ALSO LIKE:</h3>



<div class="
  summary-block-wrapper

  summary-block-collection-type-blog

  summary-block-setting-text-size-medium
  summary-block-setting-text-align-left

  summary-block-setting-design-list
  summary-block-setting-design-list-thumbnail-left

  summary-block-setting-metadata-position-below-content
  summary-block-setting-primary-metadata-none
  summary-block-setting-secondary-metadata-none

  summary-block-setting-show-thumbnail
  summary-block-setting-show-title
  summary-block-setting-show-price
  summary-block-setting-show-excerpt
  summary-block-setting-show-read-more-link

  

  sqs-gallery-design-list

  
  "

  
>

  <div class="summary-item-list-container sqs-gallery-container">

    <header class="summary-block-header">

      <!-- Collection Title -->
      <div class="summary-heading" data-animation-role="content">
        
          <span class="summary-header-text">Featured</span>
        
      </div>

      <!-- Carousel Nav -->
      <div class="summary-carousel-pager sqs-gallery-controls" data-animation-role="content">
        <span
          class="summary-carousel-pager-prev previous"
          tabindex="0"
          role="button"
          aria-label="Previous"
        ></span>
        <span
          class="summary-carousel-pager-next next"
          tabindex="0"
          role="button"
          aria-label="Next"
        ></span>
      </div>

    </header>

    <div class="summary-item-list sqs-gallery">

      

        <div class="
          summary-item
          summary-item-record-type-text
          sqs-gallery-design-list-slide
          
           summary-item-has-thumbnail
           summary-item-has-excerpt
          summary-item-has-cats
          summary-item-has-tags
          summary-item-has-author
          
          "
          >

          
            <!-- Thumbnail -->
            

  
  <div class="summary-thumbnail-outer-container">
    <a
      
        
          href="/read/betrayal-denial-and-the-bloody-beauty-of-it-all"
        
      
      class="
        summary-thumbnail-container
        sqs-gallery-image-container
        
      "
      data-title="Been burned? Betrayal, denial, and the bloody beauty of it all."
      data-description=""
    >
      <div class="summary-thumbnail img-wrapper" data-animation-role="image">
  

    

        <!-- Main Image -->
        <img src="https://images.SOURCE-cdn.com/content/v1/5c5a0a8f9b7d1526e92feb59/1605112015118-3T1632NBIJK9KI0FD3LJ/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kF5UcQgsrEa5M_kXB3FEJvp7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z5QHyNOqBUUEtDDsRWrJLTmYOVD9IE-axc7RUTDo4v7t9wzK2NOQ9LLKO3ltw4ueDjZj2DuUPWsPw7nxIZ6vyu1/WisdomPost-11.16.2020-Betrayal.Greatest+Hits_SQ.Feature.CLIENT+CLIENTLAST.png" data-image="https://images.SOURCE-cdn.com/content/v1/5c5a0a8f9b7d1526e92feb59/1605112015118-3T1632NBIJK9KI0FD3LJ/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kF5UcQgsrEa5M_kXB3FEJvp7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z5QHyNOqBUUEtDDsRWrJLTmYOVD9IE-axc7RUTDo4v7t9wzK2NOQ9LLKO3ltw4ueDjZj2DuUPWsPw7nxIZ6vyu1/WisdomPost-11.16.2020-Betrayal.Greatest+Hits_SQ.Feature.CLIENT+CLIENTLAST.png" data-image-dimensions="1081x1080" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" alt="Been burned? Betrayal, denial, and the bloody beauty of it all."  data-load="false" class="summary-thumbnail-image"/>

    

    

        

        

      </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Products: Quick View -->
    

  </div>
  



          

          <div class="summary-content sqs-gallery-meta-container" data-animation-role="content">

            <!-- Metadata (Above Title) -->
            <div class="summary-metadata-container summary-metadata-container--above-title">
              
              <div class="summary-metadata summary-metadata--primary">

    












</div>
              
              <div class="summary-metadata summary-metadata--secondary">

    












</div>
            </div>

            
              <!-- Title -->
              <div class="summary-title">
                <a
                
                  
                    href="/read/betrayal-denial-and-the-bloody-beauty-of-it-all"
                  
                
                class="summary-title-link">Been burned? Betrayal, denial, and the bloody beauty of it all.</a></div>
            

            <!-- Metadata (Below Title) -->
            <div class="summary-metadata-container summary-metadata-container--below-title">
            
              <div class="summary-metadata summary-metadata--primary">

    












</div>
              
              <div class="summary-metadata summary-metadata--secondary">

    












</div>
            </div>

            
              
            

            
              
              <!-- Excerpt -->
                <div class="summary-excerpt">
                  <p style="white-space:pre-wrap;">I’ve been betrayed — severely. Thank God. Betrayal is such a defining experience — it lays your heart bare, and that’s a bloody, good thing. Bloody good.</p><p style="white-space:pre-wrap;">Being betrayed by another person is often (not always,) a reflection of how you were betraying yourself. It’s a lie looking back at you.</p>
                </div>
              

              

              
                <!-- Read More Link -->
                <a href="/read/betrayal-denial-and-the-bloody-beauty-of-it-all" class="summary-read-more-link">Read More &#8594;</a>
              
            

            <!-- Metadata (Below Content) -->
            <div class="summary-metadata-container summary-metadata-container--below-content">
              
              <div class="summary-metadata summary-metadata--primary">

    












</div>
              
              <div class="summary-metadata summary-metadata--secondary">

    












</div>
            </div>

          </div> <!-- End .summary-content -->

        </div> <!-- End .summary-item -->

      

        <div class="
          summary-item
          summary-item-record-type-text
          sqs-gallery-design-list-slide
          
           summary-item-has-thumbnail
           summary-item-has-excerpt
          summary-item-has-cats
          summary-item-has-tags
          summary-item-has-author
          
          "
          >

          
            <!-- Thumbnail -->
            

  
  <div class="summary-thumbnail-outer-container">
    <a
      
        
          href="/read/defining-spiritual-bypassing"
        
      
      class="
        summary-thumbnail-container
        sqs-gallery-image-container
        
      "
      data-title="Defining “Spiritual bypassing.” Overused and misused but still… very useful."
      data-description=""
    >
      <div class="summary-thumbnail img-wrapper" data-animation-role="image">
  

    

        <!-- Main Image -->
        <img src="https://images.SOURCE-cdn.com/content/v1/5c5a0a8f9b7d1526e92feb59/1601571151722-TZFB8N3D3OGUS435OODH/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kF5UcQgsrEa5M_kXB3FEJvp7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z5QHyNOqBUUEtDDsRWrJLTmYOVD9IE-axc7RUTDo4v7t9wzK2NOQ9LLKO3ltw4ueDjZj2DuUPWsPw7nxIZ6vyu1/WisdomPost-10.5.2020-PleasantDistractions_SQ.Feature.CLIENT+CLIENTLAST.png" data-image="https://images.SOURCE-cdn.com/content/v1/5c5a0a8f9b7d1526e92feb59/1601571151722-TZFB8N3D3OGUS435OODH/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kF5UcQgsrEa5M_kXB3FEJvp7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z5QHyNOqBUUEtDDsRWrJLTmYOVD9IE-axc7RUTDo4v7t9wzK2NOQ9LLKO3ltw4ueDjZj2DuUPWsPw7nxIZ6vyu1/WisdomPost-10.5.2020-PleasantDistractions_SQ.Feature.CLIENT+CLIENTLAST.png" data-image-dimensions="1081x1080" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" alt="Defining “Spiritual bypassing.” Overused and misused but still… very useful."  data-load="false" class="summary-thumbnail-image"/>

    

    

        

        

      </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Products: Quick View -->
    

  </div>
  



          

          <div class="summary-content sqs-gallery-meta-container" data-animation-role="content">

            <!-- Metadata (Above Title) -->
            <div class="summary-metadata-container summary-metadata-container--above-title">
              
              <div class="summary-metadata summary-metadata--primary">

    












</div>
              
              <div class="summary-metadata summary-metadata--secondary">

    












</div>
            </div>

            
              <!-- Title -->
              <div class="summary-title">
                <a
                
                  
                    href="/read/defining-spiritual-bypassing"
                  
                
                class="summary-title-link">Defining “Spiritual bypassing.” Overused and misused but still… very useful.</a></div>
            

            <!-- Metadata (Below Title) -->
            <div class="summary-metadata-container summary-metadata-container--below-title">
            
              <div class="summary-metadata summary-metadata--primary">

    












</div>
              
              <div class="summary-metadata summary-metadata--secondary">

    












</div>
            </div>

            
              
            

            
              
              <!-- Excerpt -->
                <div class="summary-excerpt">
                  <p class="">Like too much of anything, spiritual bypassing can numb us out from our Truth—which is where the healing answers wait to be found.</p>
                </div>
              

              

              
                <!-- Read More Link -->
                <a href="/read/defining-spiritual-bypassing" class="summary-read-more-link">Read More &#8594;</a>
              
            

            <!-- Metadata (Below Content) -->
            <div class="summary-metadata-container summary-metadata-container--below-content">
              
              <div class="summary-metadata summary-metadata--primary">

    












</div>
              
              <div class="summary-metadata summary-metadata--secondary">

    












</div>
            </div>

          </div> <!-- End .summary-content -->

        </div> <!-- End .summary-item -->

      

        <div class="
          summary-item
          summary-item-record-type-text
          sqs-gallery-design-list-slide
          
           summary-item-has-thumbnail
           summary-item-has-excerpt
          summary-item-has-cats
          summary-item-has-tags
          summary-item-has-author
          
          "
          >

          
            <!-- Thumbnail -->
            

  
  <div class="summary-thumbnail-outer-container">
    <a
      
        
          href="/read/cognitive-dissonance-and-luminosity"
        
      
      class="
        summary-thumbnail-container
        sqs-gallery-image-container
        
      "
      data-title="Cognitive dissonance and our luminosity"
      data-description=""
    >
      <div class="summary-thumbnail img-wrapper" data-animation-role="image">
  

    

        <!-- Main Image -->
        <img src="https://images.SOURCE-cdn.com/content/v1/5c5a0a8f9b7d1526e92feb59/1600250171098-SRUG7PPL0FA1TFPW6EWQ/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kF5UcQgsrEa5M_kXB3FEJvp7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z5QHyNOqBUUEtDDsRWrJLTmYOVD9IE-axc7RUTDo4v7t9wzK2NOQ9LLKO3ltw4ueDjZj2DuUPWsPw7nxIZ6vyu1/WisdomPost-9.21.2020-Cognitive-Dissonance_SQ.Feature.CLIENT+CLIENTLAST.png" data-image="https://images.SOURCE-cdn.com/content/v1/5c5a0a8f9b7d1526e92feb59/1600250171098-SRUG7PPL0FA1TFPW6EWQ/ke17ZwdGBToddI8pDm48kF5UcQgsrEa5M_kXB3FEJvp7gQa3H78H3Y0txjaiv_0fDoOvxcdMmMKkDsyUqMSsMWxHk725yiiHCCLfrh8O1z5QHyNOqBUUEtDDsRWrJLTmYOVD9IE-axc7RUTDo4v7t9wzK2NOQ9LLKO3ltw4ueDjZj2DuUPWsPw7nxIZ6vyu1/WisdomPost-9.21.2020-Cognitive-Dissonance_SQ.Feature.CLIENT+CLIENTLAST.png" data-image-dimensions="1081x1080" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" alt="Cognitive dissonance and our luminosity"  data-load="false" class="summary-thumbnail-image"/>

    

    

        

        

      </div>
    </a>

    <!-- Products: Quick View -->
    

  </div>
  



          

          <div class="summary-content sqs-gallery-meta-container" data-animation-role="content">

            <!-- Metadata (Above Title) -->
            <div class="summary-metadata-container summary-metadata-container--above-title">
              
              <div class="summary-metadata summary-metadata--primary">

    












</div>
              
              <div class="summary-metadata summary-metadata--secondary">

    












</div>
            </div>

            
              <!-- Title -->
              <div class="summary-title">
                <a
                
                  
                    href="/read/cognitive-dissonance-and-luminosity"
                  
                
                class="summary-title-link">Cognitive dissonance and our luminosity</a></div>
            

            <!-- Metadata (Below Title) -->
            <div class="summary-metadata-container summary-metadata-container--below-title">
            
              <div class="summary-metadata summary-metadata--primary">

    












</div>
              
              <div class="summary-metadata summary-metadata--secondary">

    












</div>
            </div>

            
              
            

            
              
              <!-- Excerpt -->
                <div class="summary-excerpt">
                  <p class=""><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=If%20you%E2%80%99re%20paying%20attention%20to%20your%20choices,%20you%E2%80%99ll%20cognitive%20dissonance%20pang%20once%20in%20a%20while.%20%E2%80%94%20%40CLIENTDOMAIN%20https%3A//BLAH/3bAPDNF%20%23cognitivedissonance%20%23luminous" target="_blank"><strong>If you’re paying attention to your choices, you’ll cognitive dissonance pang once in a while.</strong></a><strong> And it can be a smidge shamey. But when you apply compassion to that sensation it shows itself as your conscience. And it’s a signal to </strong><a href="https://www.CLIENTDOMAIN.com/read/the-in-between-place-youre-in-its-real"><strong>get into alignment with your higher nature</strong></a><strong>. Either examine and change your perspective, or shift your actions.</strong></p>
                </div>
              

              

              
                <!-- Read More Link -->
                <a href="/read/cognitive-dissonance-and-luminosity" class="summary-read-more-link">Read More &#8594;</a>
              
            

            <!-- Metadata (Below Content) -->
            <div class="summary-metadata-container summary-metadata-container--below-content">
              
              <div class="summary-metadata summary-metadata--primary">

    












</div>
              
              <div class="summary-metadata summary-metadata--secondary">

    












</div>
            </div>

          </div> <!-- End .summary-content -->

        </div> <!-- End .summary-item -->

      

    </div> <!-- End .summary-item-list -->

  </div> <!-- End .summary-item-list-container -->

</div>]]></content:encoded>
      <excerpt:encoded><![CDATA[<p class="">What if <em>every obstacle</em> in your path was a<strong> </strong><a href="https://CLIENTDOMAIN.mykajabi.com/heart-centered-2021" target="_blank"><strong>gift of Loving Kindness</strong></a> from your Higher Self? An opportunity to transform a wound into Divine Power. Fractured awareness into wisdom. Contraction into openness… <br><br>Suddenly setbacks become love notes, inviting us into <a href="https://CLIENTDOMAIN.mykajabi.com/heart-centered-2021" target="_blank">deeper exploration of our True Nature</a>.</p>]]></excerpt:encoded>
      <wp:post_name>what-if-you-looked-at-setbacks-like-this</wp:post_name>
      <wp:post_type>post</wp:post_type>
      <wp:post_id>0</wp:post_id>
      <wp:status>pending</wp:status>
      <pubDate>Tue, 30 Mar 2021 12:00:00 +0000</pubDate>
      <wp:post_date>2021-03-30 12:00:00</wp:post_date>
      <wp:post_date_gmt>2021-03-30 12:00:00</wp:post_date_gmt>
      <category domain="post_tag" nicename="the-latest"><![CDATA[the latest]]></category>
      <category domain="post_tag" nicename="heart-centered"><![CDATA[heart centered]]></category>
      <category domain="post_tag" nicename="membership"><![CDATA[membership]]></category>
      <category domain="post_tag" nicename="practices"><![CDATA[practices]]></category>
      <category domain="post_tag" nicename="meditation"><![CDATA[meditation]]></category>
      <category domain="post_tag" nicename="journaling"><![CDATA[journaling]]></category>
      <category domain="category" nicename="heart-centered"><![CDATA[Heart Centered]]></category>
      <category domain="category" nicename="the-latest"><![CDATA[the latest]]></category>
      <dc:creator>CLIENT</dc:creator>
      <wp:comment_status>closed</wp:comment_status>
      <wp:postmeta>
        <wp:meta_key>_thumbnail_id</wp:meta_key>
        <wp:meta_value><![CDATA[1]]></wp:meta_value>
      </wp:postmeta>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: I think you have to remove the leading `/` and the `/gms` at the end like `\<hr \/><h3 style="white-space:pre-wrap;">YOU MAY ALSO LIKE:<\/h3>([\s\S]*?)<\/div>\]\]>`

Comment: @Thefourthbird yes, I have already removed those but it still does not work. Do you have Sublime? if so, copy and paste the content and then do a regex find and paste in the expression I posted minus the escapes on the front and end.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I must have missed an escape because your way worked! make this an answer and I will except it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Sublime Text Unofficial Documentation](https://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html) Sublime uses the Boost library and this part at the start of the pattern `\<` is a [Word boundary](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html#boost_regex.syntax.perl_syntax.word_boundaries) and therefore you are missing the leading `<` in `<hr />` as there is a word boundary between `<` and `h`

Also, in pattern that you tried, the leading `/` and trailing `/gms` are perhaps copied and the `/` are meant as pattern delimiters and the `gms` meant as flags.

A format like that can for example be used with Javascript, but in Sublime it would match those character literally.

In the pattern that you finally used you don't have to escape the `]` and you also don't have to escape the `/`

The pattern could look like:

```
<hr /><h3 style="white-space:pre-wrap;">YOU MAY ALSO LIKE:</h3>([\s\S]*?)</div>]]>
```